# android service need to stop after sometime

Tags: android, service

I am running a `Service` using `AlarmManager`. The `Service` is running ok and I am stopping the `Service` manually (clicking a `Button`), but I need to stop the `Service` after sometime (it may be 10 seconds). I can use `this.stopSelf();`, but how do I call `this.stopSelf();`  after some given time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should consider using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)? It will be stopped when there is no work for it so you don't need to manage its state by yourself.

Comment: Thanks you a lot Mr.Andrei Mankevich.

Answer (score 5):

This can easily be accomplished using `timer` and `timerTask` together.

I still do not know why this answer was not suggested and instead the provided answers do not provide the direct and simple solution.

In the service subclass, create these globally (you can create them not globally, but you might bump into issues)

```
//TimerTask that will cause the run() runnable to happen.
TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {
        stopSelf();
    }
};


//Timer that will make the runnable run.
Timer myTimer = new Timer();

//the amount of time after which you want to stop the service
private final long INTERVAL = 5000; // I choose 5 seconds
```

Now inside your `onCreate()` of the service, do the following :

`myTimer.schedule(myTask, INTERVAL);`

This should stop the service after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Use **postDelayed** method of `Handler` within service to get it done. For example:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        stopSelf();
    }
}, 10000);    //will stop service after 10 seconds
```

Comment: It is showing error `The method postDelayed(new Runnable(){}, int) is undefined for the type Handler`. Another error is `The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method`.

Comment: put a part of your code in http://pastebin.com/ and paste the link here. Let me see how you are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

In **Kotlin** you can use this code to stop service inside the **onStartCommand()** method:

```
 Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ stopSelf() }, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an `Intent` to start the `Service`. Set the `action` to a custom action, say `"com.yourapp.action.stopservice"`.
2. Using `AlarmManager`, start the `Intent` to start the `Service` (whatever you are doing right now). This will be delivered to the `onStartCommand()` of the `Service`, if it is is already running.
3. In `onStartCommand()`, check the `action` of the incoming `Intent`. If `action.equals("com.yourapp.action.stopservice")`, stop the `Service` using `this.stopSelf()`.

Comment: Thank you aswin kumar.But i can not understand your approach.I just need to stop the service after some times.after some times i will call `this.stopSelf()`. I want to call from `onCreate()`.

Comment: Once the service is started, onCreate won't be called. All subsequent calls will be delivered to onStartCommand(). I suggest you go through the lifecycle of a Service.

Comment: Between, answer by [Waqas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/966550/waqas) is a better solution

Comment: Thank you Mr.Aswin Kumar for your advice.surely i will implement it in future. By the way,i solved my problem creating a counter and when counter reaches my desired time i just use `stopSelf`